# PHP - Parse specific data using simplexml

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file as below.
I would like to display only data for the language en
depending on the language of the site

My php code now displays the data for all languages

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('https:/dffsfdsdf.en/export.php');
    foreach ($xml->AD as $foo)
    { ?>

    <div class="item">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>/?ID=<?php echo $foo->ID?>" class="title">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6"><h3><?php echo $foo->JOB_TITLE?></h3></div>
            <div class="col-3 text-center"><?php echo $foo->CITY?></div>
            <div class="col-3 text-right"><span class="see"><span class="close"><?php _e('more', ''); ?></span></span></div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php }
?>
```

my simplexml

```
<AD UID="MzMwODFfMF8yNTM4_0">
 <ID>MzMwOTJfMF8yNTM4_0</ID>
 <JOB_TITLE>...</JOB_TITLE>
 <CATEGORY>0</CATEGORY>
 <CATEGORY2>0</CATEGORY2>
 <EXP_DATE>2020-02-17</EXP_DATE>
 <START_DATE>2020-01-18</START_DATE>
 <COMPANY>...</COMPANY>
 <REGION_ID>7</REGION_ID>
 <CITY>...</CITY>
 <APPLY_LINK>...</APPLY_LINK>
 <REF_NO>...</REF_NO>
 <LOGO>...</LOGO>
 <FULL_HTML>...</FULL_HTML>
 <LANGUAGE>
  <![CDATA[ EN ]]>
 </LANGUAGE>
</AD>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to search where the `<LANGUAGE>` element contains a specific language.  This is hardcoded with `EN`, but the idea is just the same....

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//AD[normalize-space(LANGUAGE)="EN"]') as $foo)
```

I've used `normalize-space(LANGUAGE)` as this removes any surrounding space, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You might use and if statement to check for `EN` and use `LIBXML_NOCDATA` to turn the CDATA part into a string. Then you could use trim to so a string compare.

Note that the xml is missing a `<` at the top.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(
    'https:/dffsfdsdf.en/export.php', 
    'SimpleXMLElement', 
    LIBXML_NOCDATA
);

foreach ($xml->AD as $foo) {
    if (trim($foo->LANGUAGE) === "EN") {
        // ... your code
    }
}
```